# How is placing determined at the beginning of a race?

Tags: mario-kart-tour

At the beginning of a race, sometimes it has me in 8th, sometimes in 1st, and other times I'm somewhere in the middle. I can't really determine if there is a pattern - it doesn't seem to be related to how I did in previous races.

How is my starting position determined? Is it random?

Answer (score 1):

Just as you said, it's completely random. There's no rhyme or reason to how the game places you in each match, as you can restart the race, and start in a completely different position than you were in previously. You can start a race with the highest possible race point multipliers in all 3 categories (racer, glider, kart), and still start in last occasionally.

Comment: Is this from your own experience, or is there a source that confirms this?

Comment: Experience. There's no official source showing this